# How do printf and scanf work?

Tags: io

I have googled a lot to know how scanf and printf works.
But did not find any suitable answer.
Please help me.
Let say when we write

`scanf("%d", i); // int i`

how computer comes to know that the value has been entered from keyboard?
and how printf prints the data or output to the screen?

Please help me

Comment: It's kind of impossible to answer this here. You could probably do a full lecture or two on this subject. Download the Linux and glib source and take a look at how printf(3) and scanf(3) are implemented. (if linux isn't your think, pick your flavor, *bsd, darwin, whatever)

Comment: On which level do you mean that? If you like to know how it works on the machine level this depends a lot on the operating system you are using.

Comment: This seems like kind of the same thing as [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1253132/151344)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They use the system primitives `read` and `write`. You can see more about them here http://comsci.liu.edu/~murali/unix/read.htm and here http://codewiki.wikidot.com/c:system-calls:write and respectively read from stdin(file desc = 0) and stdout(file desc=1).